Failed to mount "917 MB Volume"
I'm a new user, following the official guide to install Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS, and whenever I try to actually install it on my new PC, it keeps giving me an error message saying:
Error mounting /dev/loop2 at /media/ubuntu/disk: /dev/loop2 already mounted or mount point busy

Does anyone know how to fix this?
If it helps, I'll note that I built my PC (for the first time)
EDIT 1: For those asking:

I downloaded the Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS image
Flashed it onto a USB drive using balenaEtcher
Plugged it into my new PC before booting it
Followed the instructions of the installation wizard exactly
Chose interactive installation, extended selection, both
recommended software options
Finally chose to erase the disk and install.

Additionally, the PC I built was only connected to the internet via ethernet cable
EDIT 2: My PC boots in UEFI mode, has 64 GB RAM, and a 2TB SSD
Also, I'm so new to Linux that I don't know how to run something like:
sudo fdisk -l (ele)

EDIT 3:
I forgot to mention this in my original question because of everything else going on, but sometime when I get to the disk setup stage, it only gives me the option of manual installation, and when I attempt to follow a tutorial to do so, it crashes, and only then gives me more options
EDIT 4: Result of sudo fdisk -l
Disk /dev/loop0: 1.63 GiB, 1752752128 bytes, 3423344 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk /dev/loop1: 471.01 MiB, 493887488 bytes, 964624 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk /dev/loop2: 874.37 MiB, 916840448 bytes, 1790704 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk /dev/loop3: 4 KiB, 4096 bytes, 8 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk /dev/loop4: 74.27 MiB, 77881344 bytes, 152112 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk /dev/loop5: 269.77 MiB, 282873856 bytes, 552488 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk /dev/loop6: 10.72 MiB, 11239424 bytes, 21952 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk /dev/loop7: 505.09 MiB, 529625088 bytes, 1034424 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk /dev/sda: 114.61 GiB, 123060879360 bytes, 240353280 sectors
Disk model:  SanDisk 3.2Gen1
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: EED3DE8A-ACD3-4541-BA15-9014C007D874
Device        Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1        64  12105119  12105056   5.8G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda2  12105120  12115263     10144     5M EFI System
/dev/sda3  12115264  12115863       600   300K Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda4  12115968 240351231 228235264 108.8G Linux filesystem
Disk /dev/loop8: 38.83 MiB, 40714240 bytes, 79520 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk /dev/loop9: 91.69 MiB, 96141312 bytes, 187776 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk /dev/loop10: 10.54 MiB, 11051008 bytes, 21584 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk /dev/loop11: 500 KiB, 512000 bytes, 1000 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk /dev/loop12: 149.63 MiB, 156901376 bytes, 306448 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk /dev/loop13: 116.78 MiB, 122449920 bytes, 239160 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk /dev/loop14: 333.79 MiB, 350007296 bytes, 683608 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk /dev/loop15: 2.72 MiB, 2850816 bytes, 5568 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk /dev/loop16: 2.71 MiB, 2846720 bytes, 5560 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

This itsFOSS Article describes what loop devices are. You probably nered to [edit] your question to clearly indicate the steps you actually took to install rather than just reference an article. Is the 917Mb volume a extra device in your system other than the one you installed the OS on? [edit] in to your question.

@kyodake The results of sudo fdisk -l (ele) are bash: syntax error near unexpected token \('` so I'm sure you didn't mean that and the OP is confused and wrote "Also, I'm so new to Linux that I don't know how to run something like: sudo fdisk -l (ele)". Please post a new comment and correct the syntax error. Thanks in advance.

Open a terminal by pressing: Control + T, run in it by typing and pressing enter sudo fdisk -l , it is not one, the password when you type it is not visible, it is the password of the live session. Copy and paste the result into the post, editing it. Also copy how much RAM you have and if your computer boots in UEFI or BIOS mode.

Hey everyone, I bypassed these issues by choosing only the most barebones installation options, but ran into another problem I posted about here
